# How to create a 2d array which dimensions are specified by user (in jQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs

I need to create a 2D array with dimension specified in input fields. And fill the generated fields  so that it spirals clock-wise, starting from the bottom right corner.

[image]

I managed to create the 2D array but I don't know how to fill it. Any help is appreciated.

```
$("button").click(function()
{
    var brr=parseInt($("#brr").val());
    var brs=parseInt($("#brs").val());
    for (i=1; i<=brs; i++)
    {
        for (j=1; j<=brr; j++)
        {
            $("#output").append("<div class='k'>o</div>");
        }
        $("#output").append("<br/>");
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1):

something like this?

[http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/d0beygLp](http://jsfiddle.net/mig1098/d0beygLp/)

```
$("#button").click(function()              
{        
    $("#output").html('');
    var brs1=parseInt($("#brs1").val());
    var brs2=parseInt($("#brs2").val());
    var c=0;
    for (i=1; i<=brs1; i++){

     for (j=1; j<=brs2; j++){
        $("#output").append("<div class='k'>"+c+"</div>");
         c++;
     }
    $("#output").append("<div class=\"clearfix\"></div>");
    }

});
```

Comment: I added a picture how it should look like, but I didn't  realized that I needed reputation to post pictures. I edited the question now. So could I trouble you for another moment. :D
Btw thx this was also helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can populate it this way: [LIVE EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/cg76twar/)

```
 $("button").click(function() 
 {

    var brr=parseInt($("#brr").val());
    var brs=parseInt($("#brs").val());

    var counter = brr * brs;

    for (i=1; i<=brs; i++){

        for (j=1; j<=brr; j++)
        {

          $("#output").append("<div class='k'>" + (counter--) + "</div>");

        }

        $("#output").append("<br/>");

    }

});
```